# Docker - MySQL mount/bind with local machine mysql data /var/lib/mysql

Tags: mysql, mongodb, docker

i have installed mysql on my local machine and i have docker installed in my machine i am converting my projects to Docker successfully i have deployed flask on container but i want to install  mysql on container but mysql container should use my local machine data because data almost 100+Gb in size.

I have to do Same for mongodb.

Am i missing something for dockerize the existing mysql and mongodb.

**OS: Ubuntu and default mysql path: /var/lib/mysql**

I dont want to do import/export.

**Below is my docker-compose.yml**

```
  version: "3"
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: ./app
      dockerfile: ./dockerfile      
    container_name: flaskPython
    links:
      - mysqldb
      - mongodb
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
  myadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        container_name: phpmyadmin
        ports:
            - "8282:80"
        environment:
            - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
            - PMA_HOST=${MYSQL_HOST}
        restart: always
        depends_on:
            - mysqldb
            - mongodb  
  mysqldb:
        image: mysql:${MYSQL_VERSION}
        container_name: ${MYSQL_HOST}
        restart: 'always'
        expose:
            - '3306'
        env_file:
            - ".env"
        environment:
            - MYSQL_DATABASE=${MYSQL_DATABASE}
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
            - MYSQL_USER=${MYSQL_USER}
            - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
        ports:
            - "8989:3306"
        volumes:
            #- ./data/db/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
            - /var/lib/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
  mongodb:
        image: mongo
        container_name: mongodb
        restart: always
        environment:

          - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
          - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
        # if you wish to setup additional user accounts specific per DB or with different roles you can use following entry point
        #no --auth is needed here as presence of username and password add this option automatically
        command: mongod
        ports:
            - "27017:27017"
        volumes:
          #- ./data/db/mongo/001_users.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/001_users.js:ro
          - ./mongo-entrypoint/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
          - ./data/db/mongo:/usr/data/db
```

Logs:

```
2019-02-01T16:08:20.100825Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2019-02-01T16:08:20.101919Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.22) starting as process 1 ...
2019-02-01T16:08:20.104031Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2019-02-01T16:08:20.104043Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2019-02-01T16:08:20.104046Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2019-02-01T16:08:20.104048Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2019-02-01T16:08:20.104050Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2019-02-01T16:08:20.104052Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2019-02-01T16:08:20.104214Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2019-02-01T16:08:20.104285Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2019-02-01T16:08:20.105476Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2019-02-01T16:08:20.110790Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-02-01T16:08:20.112288Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2019-02-01T16:08:20.123892Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2019-02-01T16:08:20.139921Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2019-02-01T16:08:20.139996Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2019-02-01T16:08:20.170786Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2019-02-01T16:08:20.173104Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2019-02-01T16:08:20.173143Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2019-02-01T16:08:20.174483Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2019-02-01T16:08:20.224878Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.22 started; log sequence number 1529088986
2019-02-01T16:08:20.225403Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2019-02-01T16:08:20.225887Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2019-02-01T16:08:20.231185Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 190201 16:08:20
2019-02-01T16:08:20.233231Z 0 [Warning] Failed to set up SSL because of the following SSL library error: SSL context is not usable without certificate and private key
2019-02-01T16:08:20.233502Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2019-02-01T16:08:20.233535Z 0 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2019-02-01T16:08:20.233544Z 0 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2019-02-01T16:08:20.233556Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2019-02-01T16:08:20.236451Z 0 [Warning] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2019-02-01T16:08:20.248740Z 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2019-02-01T16:08:20.248832Z 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2019-02-01T16:08:20.248857Z 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2019-02-01T16:08:20.248875Z 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'debian-sys-maint@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2019-02-01T16:08:20.248921Z 0 [Warning] 'db' entry 'performance_schema mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2019-02-01T16:08:20.248935Z 0 [Warning] 'db' entry 'sys mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2019-02-01T16:08:20.249216Z 0 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2019-02-01T16:08:20.256300Z 0 [Warning] 'tables_priv' entry 'user mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2019-02-01T16:08:20.256349Z 0 [Warning] 'tables_priv' entry 'sys_config mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2019-02-01T16:08:20.301149Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2019-02-01T16:08:20.301811Z 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.22'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

I want to use machine mysql data in mysql container so that i dont have to migrate 100+ gb data to mysql container, so that my mysql container will use my local machine mysql data for read and write purpose.

PS: i just want i dont migrate machine mysql data to mysql container so that my mysql container somehow link to my machine and use my local machine installed mysql data folder.

Comment: where is your mysql data in your local machine? and whether you are using Docker Toolbox in windows or in just docker ce in linux?

Comment: if you are using docker toolbox in windows , by default C drive is mounted, so it becomses , mandatory to save and run your project from C drive and provide the full path to your volumes . for example --volume /c/Users/%USER%/.... : ./var/lib/mysql

Comment: sorry dude i am not using windows i am on ubuntu 18.04 and updated my question

Comment: then, it seems fine

Comment: What is the actual question here? You've stated what you want to do, and you included a docker-compose.yml file, but I don't know what the problem or error message you are running into looks like... just that you are "missing something". Please expand your question to include more about the error and ask a specific question.

Comment: Still can't get what the problem is. You get exceptions when starting the container? Are you able to connect to docker's mysql server via mysql client? Does your mysql server on host machine run also on 3306? Be more descriptive so we can help you.

Comment: @leopal i am unable to connect to docker mysql with pymongo  yes machine mysql running with 3306 and container with  8989 i have updated the question again

Comment: more updated the question with new logs